# sapply() fucntion to generate summary statistics, need to remove a column before I use the function

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to generate summary statistics by using `sapply` on 5 columns with numerical data. There is however 1 column with sex F/M (which is the second column of my dataframe), which I do not need to apply this to.  I have tried removing the column by using

```
data_2 <- data_2[,2]
```

and a bunch of other methods but they do not seem to remove the column.
I have to work out the mean, sd, min, max and sample size with the `sapply` function.

Comment: this seems homework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I find it easier to use indices, instead of the data itself:

```
sapply((1:ncol(data_2))[-2], function(i) {
  c(mean(data_2[,i]), sd(data_2[,i])) # add other functions
})
```

Comment: I suppose you mean to have `sd(data_2[, i])`. For data frames the following is simpler: `sapply(data_2[, -2], function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x)))`.

Comment: Yeah, whoops. I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
data_2 <- data_2[, -2]
```

minus removes the column, without the minus you're just returning the second column.

However overwriting `data_2` with `data_2[, -2]` is not optimal, so better just to run `sapply` on `data_2[, -2]`.